# Macs won't connect to Belkin router's wifi, but USB dongle and android devices will

Tags: network, wifi, router

Belkin N300 (crap router I know)

Newest MBP running 10.11
Newest MBP running 10.10

Can't connect to wifi. It'll say, could not connect to [SSID]. Try moving closer to the router and please try again.

Now, the weird part is, 10.11 mac is connected to the same wifi via a little USB 802.11n NIC. An android phone and an android tablet are also connected right now.

Still, both macs using their normal built-in NICs are incapable of joining! I've been spinning through all the options on the router, scouring google, to no avail. Both macs work fine, were just connected to another wifi earlier this morning and all week long (an identically-configured, identical-model Belkin N300 although I think it's channel was set to Auto), the 10.11 mac even connected to this SSID earlier. It was upon shifting channel from 10 to 6, and then from that point on, neither mac would connect.

I don't think changing the channel from 10 to 6 can cause this, because I've changed channels before, and it's not a problem.

I've tried all the usual things, looked through tons of settings. It seems very unlikely the problem lives within the macs, seeing as they were connected to a Belkin N300 earlier this morning, and the one even connected to this one for a little bit.

The only interesting thing I've noticed is that Wireless Diagnostics scan sees the SSID as being B/G/N, though the settings in the router's settings are N only.

Any ideas?

Comment: The Belkin N300 router appears to be an 802.11n router, only. Can you verify that? If that's true, take a look at the suggestions in this post: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131455/why-doesnt-my-macbook-pro-retina-connect-to-802-11n

Comment: @TMHahn Thanks for the ideas. It's not an N only router. The only interesting thing I found in all the diagnostics I've checked is that Wireless Diagnostics Scan shows the network as B/G/N, but in the router's settings, it's set to N only (I found this yields better performance).